# Building gcc 2.95.3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gcc, glibc

I want to compile gcc-2.95.3 on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, but it won't work.

I found [this](http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=111), and [this](http://nayaneye.co.in/multi-core/gcc2.html), but nothing helped.

I first tried to build it with my 4.6.3 version of gcc, but I got an error message.
Then I tried to build gcc-3.4.6 because in the first link, this version had been used to build 2.95.3, but it was not successful either.
Trevorpounds is the best page solving this issue you can find, but it just wont work.
I tried other things too, but nothing works.

As far as I know, the newer toolchain may be the problem, but is there some way to fix that without reinstalling the whole OS?

Actually, I dont even care whether I build it myself or not, if there is a place where I can download the binaries and they work, i'm happy.

Okay, the detailed information what I did and what error messages I got:

The whole procedure is from [here](http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=111)

1) I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04

2) I detect what glibc I have installed by `ldd --version`, I got the answer `ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.5) 2.15 ...` so it is 2.15

3) I download glibc-2.15.tar.gz from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/, I save it into my Downloads folder.

4) I unpack glibc by `tar xzf glibc-2.15.tar.gz`

5) `mkdir -p gcc-2.95.3/glibc-workaround/include/bits`

6) `cp glibc-2.15/bits/stdio-lock.h gcc-2.95.3/glibc-workaround/include/bits`

7) `cp glibc-2.15/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/bits/pthreadtypes.h gcc-2.95.3/glibc-workaround/include/bits`

8) `sed -i -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/\(__pthread_slist_t __list;\n[ \t]*}\)/\1 __gcc_295_workaround__/g;p;}' gcc-2.95.3/glibc-workaround/include/bits/pthreadtypes.h`

9) Now I download gcc-2.95.3.tar.gz from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/, I also save it in my Downloads folder.

10) I unpack gcc by `tar xzf gcc-2.95.3.tar.gz`

11) `cd gcc-2.95.3`

12) I download http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/gcc-v2.95.x.debian.x86_64.diff and save it into the Downloads folder.

13) `patch -p0 < ../gcc-v2.95.x.debian.x86_64.diff` no errors occur

14) `mkdir ../gcc-2.95.3-objdir`

15) `cd ../gcc-2.95.3-objdir`

16) `../gcc-2.95.3/configure --prefix=/opt/i386/gcc/gcc-2.95.3 --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --enable-shared --host i386-pc-linux-gnu` seems to work fine

17) `make > log.txt`

This is where I get my error

I get [this](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8821292/consolelog.txt.html) in the console:

and [this](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8821288/log.txt.html) is my log.txt file:

18) The next step would be `make install` but I didn't do that, since I got the error before.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with newer version of gcc

Comment: I need to compile Quake-III-Arena. I have found the source on https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-III-Arena, but it requires gcc 2.95.3.

Comment: you should post the error output you received. You're likely missing a dependency. Also add more detail about how far you got in the tutorial.

Comment: @Odin Are you 100% sure you cannot make newer GCC compile that code? Also, check out [`ioquake`](https://github.com/ioquake/ioq3)

Comment: I'll try the compilation with the newer gcc when I have time, but I am not sure if I can use ioquake, but that would probably be the easiest way.